# Review Comments for Program Chair -- what to write?

Tags: peer-review, conference

I am preparing some reviews of conference contributions. The online review management asks me to grade the assigned papers, add comments for the authors and comments for the program chair. I cannot leave any field blank -- so I am wondering what comments I should give to the chair? To my knowledge, comments to the chair include suspected or actual cases of plagiarism.

- Is there anything else, a chair might expect to read from me, the reviewer?
- Should I give them a short version of my comments to the authors?

The conference homepage and the reviewer guidelines do not give any hints.

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no point why you should fill anything into this field, unless you actually have some confidential comments that should not be part of the comments to the authors.

You can fill the field in a boilerplate manner, by using a text fragment such as: "I do not have any additional comments beyond those to the authors."

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you make a recommendation on acceptance/rejection here and back it up with a reason or two. If there is something remarkably good or bad about the paper, mention it. You don't need to repeat what is in the author comments as that isn't exactly relevant to the job that the chair has ahead.

If you are familiar with the quality of the papers at this conference you will have an idea whether the paper measures up to the general quality. If the conference has a "best paper" award, don't neglect to make a recommendation if a paper qualifies for that.